# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null(…)

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null(…)  error while uploading image to server using cordova transfer plugin in ionic2 angular 2. here is code.

**Image picker code for saving image path:**

```
ImagePick() {
    let options = {
      destinationType   : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType        : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    };
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {


      this.Image = imageData;

      console.log(this.Image);
    }, (err) => {

      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

**File transfer options**

```
 let options = {
          fileKey: "avatar",
          fileName: "image.jpg",
          mimeType: "image/jpeg",
          params: {
            food: this.navParams.get("food"),
            location_id: this.navParams.get("location"),
            address: this.navParams.get("address"),
            instructions: this.navParams.get("instructions"),
            phone: this.myForm.controls.phone.value,
              code: "b08d131e06",
            outlets_attributes: 'outlet'
          },
          headers: {headers: this.user_service.Get_Header()}
        };

        console.log(this.Image);
```

**uploading image with other form elements using cordova transfer plugin**

```
  let fileTransfer = new Transfer();
      if(this.Image!=null && this.Image!=""){
          console.log(this.Image);
            fileTransfer.upload(this.Image, URL, options).
            then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
            }, (err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
      }
```

what i am doing wrong. need help for that... 
THANKS!

Comment: Can you please paste the complete error log ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null(…) 

just getting this error

Comment: Check in which file and line causing this error in the log.

Comment: this was happening due to header addition in option -> params ->headers: {headers: this.user_service.Get_Header()}

do you know how to add header and other form elements in params..